# Should I include the license of packages used for a personal project?

Tags: github, package, licensing

After working on a project in flask, I wondered if I should include as a third-party license, the licenses of the installed packages.

To explain myself better... I installed flask and other packages with different licenses in a virtual environment, this means that in my repository on github I have to refer to their licenses to avoid problems with copyright? Or doesn't make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the expectation for the license file in a repository is that it covers the main project, not external dependencies.  If the repository includes vendored dependencies, you should include the licenses of those vendored dependencies, which most programs that vendor data automatically do.

If you're just using modules referred to by some sort of manifest file and downloaded by a tool by the user to build or run your program, you usually don't include those in your license file.  It's expected that people interested in those licenses will query the package archive or repository for that information.